# Select files with certain ending number

Tags: r

I have some files that look like

file_a1_s1.csv

file_a2_s1.csv

...

file_a1_s10.csv

file_a1_s10.csv

...

And I only want to select those file_aX_s1.csv using `list.files(pattern=...)`. How should I write it so that only those ending with s1 can be selected (those with s10 can be ignored)?

Comment: `list.files(pattern = "_s1.csv")`?

Comment: Using globs `Sys.glob("*_s1.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `stringr::str_subset()` as in:

```
folder %>%
  list.files() %>% 
  stringr::str_subset("_s1.csv")
```